# RelativeLayout scrollabe not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a Scrollable relative layout, but when I put a `ScrollView` seems like it's useless.

My `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="20dip" android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtEmail" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvEmailRegistro"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/date" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:hint="Fecha nacimiento" android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="enviar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingLeft="15dip" android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Email"
        android:id="@+id/tvEmailRegistro"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/psw"
        android:id="@+id/tvpsw"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvpsw"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/psw2"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fecha"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/localitat"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Localidad"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Codigo postal"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the result is :

[image]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong... Can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe LinearLayout will be more helpful for you? Or attach some mock what do you want to get via RelativeLayout

Comment: Yap, that was the problem... thanks ^^

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. Could you give me vote up in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `LinearLayout` will be more helpful for you.